# Cannot upload an image while creating a Facebook Mobile App Install Ad

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-ads-api

I seem to be stuck in a dark alley with no one around and no signboards either. I'm trying to create a simple Facebook Mobile App Install Ad . . . and seem to be stuck on the 1st step since many hours. I just cannot upload a banner image.

The image is 600X360, the exact specification facebook wants.

I've tried both png and jpg

I get no error message, it just says 'Uploading' for a few seconds and then it's back to where it was as if nothing ever happened and the image is not uploaded.

I've checked by browser versions, Flash versions.

Tried with Chrome, Firefox and safari.

Tried on my mac and on Windows.

NOTHING. It just shuts up and doesn't accept the image.

Called up the toll free number given on facebook's ad setup page, which says "call for Free ad setup" . . . but the girl who picked up refused to transfer the phone the call to a tech until I commit my daily ad budget to her.

I try to tell her that I have not decided it yet and I was just trying to see the preview of how my ad will look, so I can only decide on my budget after checking the ad, selecting my target and regions.

But no, she says, it's 'Policy' to transfer the call to techs only if my budget is above a certain level . . . and all I wanna do is see the damn ad preview.

Looks like something wrong with facebook's server since it won't accept the image uplaod from all OSs, Browsers, but I don't see anyone else even talking about this so it must be just me.

It's creeping me out with supernatural superstitions about myself and if someone else has experienced this, please just tell me that you have . . . so I don't freak out that some paranormal curse has been cast on me or something.

It's creepy and I don't know what's the reason.

Thanks for listening.

And oh yeah, if someone has been through this and found a solution, please let me know.

Sean.

Answer (score 1):

go into ad manager and use the power editor tool. In there I was able to upload a photo whereas before I could not.